# Embed flash not working in Firefox

Tags: html

For some reason this code is not working in Firefox while it works on all the other browesers.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="336" height="180"><param name="movie" value="http://www.monex.com/ichart/inter_chart.swf" /><embed src="http://www.monex.com/ichart/inter_chart.swf" width="336" height="180" /></object>
```